# How do I set this animation to loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

How do I set this animation to loop?
I want that once the animation has finished, it starts over

```js
odoo.default({ el:'.js-odoo', from: 'THEWINNER', to: 'ISCOMING', animationDelay: 1000 });
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata");

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 33% 100%, #fed373 4%, #f15245 30%, #d92e7f 62%, #9b36b7 85%, #515ecf);
  font-family: "Inconsolata";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16vmin;

  fill: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-odoo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/coderitual/odoo/feature/codevember16/lib/odoo.js"></script>
```

Comment: What animation?

Comment: @Spectric https://794587.playcode.io

Answer (score 0):

This is a **workaround**,not a solution:

```js
function triggerAnimation() {
  odoo.default({ el: ".js-odoo", from: "THEWINNER", to: "ISCOMING", animationDelay: 1000 });
}

triggerAnimation();
setInterval(() => triggerAnimation(), 5500);
```

```html
<style>
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata");

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 33% 100%, #fed373 4%, #f15245 30%, #d92e7f 62%, #9b36b7 85%, #515ecf);
  font-family: "Inconsolata";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16vmin;

  fill: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>
<div class="js-odoo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/coderitual/odoo/feature/codevember16/lib/odoo.js"></script>
```

Or with alternate

```js
var alternate = true;
function triggerAnimation(fromText, toText) {
  odoo.default({ el: ".js-odoo", from: fromText, to: toText, animationDelay: 1000 });
}

triggerAnimation("THEWINNER", "ISCOMING");

setInterval(() => {
  if(alternate) {
    triggerAnimation("ISCOMING", "THEWINNER");
    alternate = false;
    return;
  }
  triggerAnimation("THEWINNER", "ISCOMING");
  alternate = true;
}, 5000);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata");

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 33% 100%, #fed373 4%, #f15245 30%, #d92e7f 62%, #9b36b7 85%, #515ecf);
  font-family: "Inconsolata";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16vmin;

  fill: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-odoo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/coderitual/odoo/feature/codevember16/lib/odoo.js"></script>
```